# TypeError: sqlrunner.run_query() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sql_string'

Tags: python, java, postgresql

Iam getting in error while error executing I coulf not find out the issue can anyone help me with this
TypeError: sqlrunner.run_query() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sql_string'

'''

```
import psycopg2

class sqlrunner():
    hostname = 'localhost'
    database = 'postgres'
    username = 'postgres'
    pwd = 'Naveen$1234'
    port_id = 5432
    table_name = 'my_table'

    def connect(self):
        self.connect = psycopg2.connect( host = self.hostname,
                                        user = self.username,
                                        password = self.pwd,
                                        dbname = self.database,
                                        port= self.port_id )
    
        self.cursor=self.connect.cursor()
    

    def run_query(self,sql_string):
        cursor=self.cursor
        sql_string = "drop table if EXISTS my_table"
        print(sql_string)
        cursor.execute(sql_string)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db=sqlrunner()
    db.connect()
    db.run_query()
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You have the query string in the method.
Two options:

1. Pass the query string as variable to the method and remove it from the method:

```py
...
db.run_query("drop table if EXISTS my_table")
```

2. Or don't add a parameter to the signature of the method:

```py
...
def run_query(self):
...
```